# Plotting group variable excluding some categories based on condition

Tags: matlab, histogram, categorical-data

I want to plot an histogram of a group variable. For this I can use categorical.

I am using an example, using summary(Group), to explain:

```
variable.group={'one','three','four','one','three','four','two','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four'}
Group=categorical(variable.group)
summary(Group)
figure,histogram(Group),title('Summary Group')
```

[image]

I could also use `tabulate(Group)` to give this result:

```
Group_tabulated =
  4×3 cell array
    'four'     [10]    [33.3333]
    'one'      [ 9]    [     30]
    'three'    [10]    [33.3333]
    'two'      [ 1]    [ 3.3333]
```

Now, as we see in above plot, there is a group with very little occurrence; I want to exclude that category to focus on the 3 most important ones.

Now using condition on tabulate, I have managed to nearly done it. But I have an issue since the category I want to exclude is still showing... just at 0 now.

```
Group_tabulated = tabulate(Group)
idx_largest=cell2mat(Group_tabulated(:,2))>3
Group_to_display=Group_tabulated(idx_largest,1)
Learn1_1n_largest=Group(ismember(Group,Group_tabulated(idx_largest,1)))
summary(Learn1_1n_largest)
figure,histogram(Learn1_1n_largest),title('Summary Group largest only')
```

[image]

**2 questions**:

1. Can we make the solution with tabulate work, so it exclude that category data from Learn1_1n_largest?
2. Can I use a different method just using some conditions on either categorical or on histogram for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I have added an example.  hope that makes it easier to understand :-)

Comment: There is something I don't understand, it is why the category 'two' is showing if it is not within the new categorical variable Learn1_1n_largest

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my first question. It is possible to use removecats in order to remove all unused categories. It is simple by just not specifying anything else that the categorical as such `Learn1_1n_largest=removecats(Learn1_1n_largest)`. The full solution to my first question is:

```
variable.group={'one','three','four','one','three','four','two','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four', ...
    'one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four','one','three','four'}
Group=categorical(variable.group)
summary(Group)
figure,histogram(Group),title('Summary Group')
Group_tabulated = tabulate(Group)
idx_largest=cell2mat(Group_tabulated(:,2))>3
Group_to_display=Group_tabulated(idx_largest,1)
Learn1_1n_largest=Group(ismember(Group,Group_tabulated(idx_largest,1)))
figure,histogram(Learn1_1n_largest),title('Summary Group largest only')
Learn1_1n_largest=removecats(Learn1_1n_largest)
figure,histogram(Learn1_1n_largest),title('Summary Group largest only')
```

I would be glad if anyone has the solution of my second question, as I hope that there would be a simpler solution without having to use both categorical & tabulate.

Thanks!